# AWS JS SDK TypeError: STS is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-sdk, yarnpkg

I'm have a ReactJS application that uses the aws-sdk for cognito login. I used `yarn` to install all modules, but when I try to access the website at localhost I get a JS error: **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: STS is not a constructor**.

The error points to this line in the `aws-sdk` credentials file:
`this.sts = this.sts || new STS(clientConfig);`

Where `STS` is from: `var STS = require('../../clients/sts');`

Any thoughts on how to resolve this error? I've tried installing other modules or upgrading them, but continue to get this error.

**EDIT - VUE.js EXAMPLE:**

```
import {
  Config as AWSConfig,
  CognitoIdentityCredentials,
} from 'aws-sdk/global';
import LexRuntime from 'aws-sdk/clients/lexruntime';
import Polly from 'aws-sdk/clients/polly';
```

Comment: I also have this problem using this library. I am bundling with Parcel.

Comment: @RobFyffe what did you do to resoved your problem?

Comment: I ended up using Vue.js as I couldn't get React to play nicely with it. Vue worked and I didn't have any issues.  I updated the question with the extent of my imports with Vue.

Answer (score 0):

I think `new STS(...)` gives you such error of **`STS in not a constructor`**.
Please get rid of `new` operator from it:

```
this.sts = this.sts || STS(clientConfig);
```

Comment: I checked where the STS class was coming from and saw it was exporting it as `AWS.STS`. So I used `|| new AWS.STS(clientConfig);`.
This resolved this specific error, but then I was getting a strange processor error that would randomly occur in a different line of code each time :/