# STS is not a constructor

Tags: typescript, react-redux, aws-sdk, aws-amplify, parcel

I am reopen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52831576/aws-js-sdk-typeerror-sts-is-not-a-constructor)

I'm have a ReactJS-Redux application that uses the aws-sdk for cognito for login. I am using with `parcel-bundler: ^1.8.1`

I activated AWS-LOGGER and have this JS error when access: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: STS is not a constructor.

The error points to this line in the aws-sdk credentials file:

```
this.sts = this.sts || new STS(clientConfig);
```

Where STS is from: `var STS = require('../../clients/sts');`

Any thoughts on how to resolve this error?

**I enabled console AWS and show this error:**

[image]

I hope that any help me

Comment: Hi Julio, Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Neill unfortunately me and my team changed to webpack